# Cannot run program /java/jdk19/ bin/java :error 13 Отказанно в доступе

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

При запуске .sh файла выводит ошибку Cannot run program /java/jdk19/ bin/java :error 13 Отказанно в доступе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой-то странный путь к Java.. Вам следует проверить, имеет ли ваш текущий пользователь право на доступ к указанному файлу, и имеет ли этот файл право на выполнение (execution).